# j_spring_security_check redirect

Tags: grails, spring-security

I upgraded my application from 2.2.3 to 2.4.3. Now when I click `submit` on the login page, I see that the POST request to `j_spring_security_check` has status code `302`.

Is there something I need to do after upgrading? I've tried running `grails clean-all` but that did not help.

I'm using this version: `compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC3'`

settings in config.groovy

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.aerstone.scanner.security.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.aerstone.scanner.security.UserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.aerstone.scanner.security.Role'
```

GSP

```
       <form action="${postUrl}" method="POST" id="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
          <input type='text'  name='j_username' id='username' placeholder="Username"/>
           <input type='password' name='j_password' id='password' placeholder="Password"/>
           <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign in" id="submit"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you include your plugin settings from Config.groovy as well as the GSP code for your login form? Also, any custom beans or filters you may have defined?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after an upgrade.

I changed the action of the login form by:

```
<form action='${ request.contextPath }/j_spring_security_check' method="POST">
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry. Could you provide the informations asked by Joshua Moore ? More details will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

please note that the name had change in the config to be:
grails.plugin.springsecurity....

Notice 'plugin' vs 'plugins'.  I've passed this problem but I'm getting invalid credentials all the time.